# Approximating a vector using Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the standard SVD decomposition of an $m$-by-$n$ matrix $A$,
$$
A=\sum_{i=1}^r \sigma_i u_i v_i^*, \qquad \text {where $r \leq \min \{m, n\}$ is the rank of $A$, }
$$
and where the singular values $\sigma_i$ are assumed to be sorted in descending order, $\sigma_i \geq \sigma_{i+1}$.

It is known (see for instance [this entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation)) that truncating the sum to the first $k < r$ terms of the sum we obtain a $k$-rank approximation to $A$,
$$
A_k = \sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i u_i v_i^*, \qquad \| A - A_k\|_F = \sqrt{\sigma_{k+1}^2+\ldots + \sigma_r^2}, \qquad \| A - A_k \|_2 = \sigma_{k+1}.
$$

The SVD decomposition, gives also a orthonormal bases for $R^m$ and $R^n$, and I wonder if any estimates can be found for
$$
\bigg\|u - \sum_{i=1}^k \langle u, u_i \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^m} \, u_i \bigg\|, \quad 
\bigg\|v - \sum_{i=1}^k \langle v, v_i \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^n} \,v_i \bigg\|
$$
for some $u \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and some choice of the norms.

Comment: Your final question seems not relevant to the low rank approximation: it is only about the projection of a vector onto some subspace. If you use the Euclidean norm, you have $\|u - \sum_{i=1}^k \langle u, u_i \rangle u_i\|_2^2 = \|\sum_{i > k} \langle u, u_i \rangle u_i\|^2 = \sum_{i > k} (\langle u, u_i \rangle)^2$ for any orthonormal basis $(u_j)$.

Comment: The $u_i$ are not any set of vectors, they are the vectors coming from the SVD, and I wonder if this can be used somehow?

Comment: But conversely, any orthonormal basis is the set of singular vectors of *some* matrix $A$. So the fact that the $u_i$ come from an SVD does not make them any more special than an arbitrary orthonormal basis.